# Recycle several application pools in bat file

Tags: batch-file, application-pool, recycle

I'm trying to recycle several of my application pool using commands in a bat file but it doesn't work.

This is my file :

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:AppPool1
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:AppPool2
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:AppPool3
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:AppPool4
```

This is the response in cmd :

```
Failed to process input: The parameter 'recycle' must begin with a / or - (HRESULT=80070057).
```

I've tried to had the command start at the beginning of each line but it doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that seems to be a very descriptive error message. did you try to follow its advice?

Comment: no because when I try to execute a single line, it works ! The error is on the second "recycle" parameter. All the commands are executed at the same tiem (in a row) so it doesn't work

Comment: how did you create the batch file? is it possible that you used unix linebreaks instead of dos/windows crlf?

Comment: that does not really answer the second question. try to open the file in regular notepad.

Comment: In the regular notepad, I saw no linebreaks ! It's weird because I always use Notepad++ and I never saw something like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you saved your file in unix format, which uses single linefeed characters. DOS/windows needs carriage-return/linefeed pairs.
check your notepad++ settings, or use regular notepad to edit the file.

edit: see here for Notepad++ line endings setting:
http://techtips-it.blogspot.co.at/2011/04/can-i-convert-file-format-in-notepad.html

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but if any one else encounters this, try running as administrator.